# How-to sign an iOS configuration profile generated programmatically?

Tags: php, ios, mdm, signing, configuration-profile

### Context

I have a webapp (frontend JS / backend PHP) that generates some [MDM iOS configuration profiles](https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf) (*.mobileconfig) programmatically.

Website users enter some informations, call my PHP api, and my PHP backend **generates a configuration profile "on-the-fly"** with the user-specific data, save it on the server, and return back the URL of the generated profile, so the user can click this link and install it on its iOS device.

In short: this profile contains in its payload only a webclip (safari shortcut).

Everything works fine, the configuration profile link opens the iOS Settings app that asks the user to install this profile on its device.

My problem is that this programmatically generated **profile is not signed**. So the user **is warned by iOS** that the profile is not signed and he must do several additional actions to confirm the profile installation.

I would like that the generated profiles to be signed, **so the user can install them more easily and quickly.**

### Questions

- is it possible?
- if yes, is it possible with PHP?
- if yes, how can I do that?

I read some ressources about signing configuration profiles, by I don't understant everything, I din't have any skills about signing, certificates etc.

That's not clear for me!

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Also with PHP.

How?

1. Save the profile you want to sign to a temp file:

   > file_put_contents ($tmp_file_name, $profile_data);
2. Sign the file you have just created:

   > $data = shell_exec ("openssl smime -sign -in $tmp_file_name {add here another parameters you need...}");
3. Send the data to the client:

   > echo $data;
4. Delete the tmp file...

   > unlink ($tmp_file_name);

Comment: That's sounds great, thanks.

However, which infos do you put on "{add here another parameters you need...}" ?

I guess I have to put some Apple certificates informations elsewhere? Is that linked to the Apple developer certificate you have to generate in order to publish apps on the appstore?

I'm sorry for being so dunb, I'm a JS frontend developer so that is really not my comfort zone!!

Comment: See here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4907079 > openssl smime \
-sign \
-signer your_server.crt
\
-inkey your_server_cert_key.pem
\
-certfile your_server_cert_chain.pem \
-nodetach \
-outform der \
-in your_unsigned_profile.mobileconfig \
-out your_signed_profile.mobileconfig

Comment: yes thaks! I saw and bookmarked this link indeed. So I guess I now have to generate *.pem files from the p12 file from the iOS developer certificate (I've read other things about that). And I have to enroll the Apple's dev program first of course, or buy another certificate.

Comment: I'd like to mark as accepted after I confirm it is working for my case, but this could take some time for me to test that so I accpet your answer, it will help me a lot. I'll tell you back here when I'll manage to have some time to implement all this. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that it works using the [@zvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1909132/zvi) answer. Thanks!

Let me give more details about my implementation to help other people. Especially I was confused by which files I need to sign and how to get them.

**1. Get a certificate**

I used a free certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), through [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/free-ssl/#crt) to get easily the 2 files needed (certificate and private key).

*You'll need to proove that the domain is yours (using FTP or DNS method)*

I saved the certificate as ***"certificate.crt"*** and the private key as ***"private-key.pem"***. Upload them somewhere to your server.

**2. Get the certificate authority chain file**

If you just use the 2 files above, your profile will be signed bu not "verified" in iOS (the green check sign I was looking for)

Download the "Chain of Trust" from [this page](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/).

I used the "Let’s Encrypt Authority X3 (IdenTrust cross-signed)" one, and saved it to ***"ca-chain.pem"***. Upload it to your server with the two other ones.

**3. Make a PHP signin method**

To sign it through a PHP script, I made a method for that, taking an input profile file (not signed) and writing to an output profile file (signed).

I used [the method descibed here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4907079) to call the *openssl* command from PHP using *shell_exec*

```
<?php
function sslSignProfileToFile($inputFile, $outputFile)
{
    $sslPath = '/absolute/path/to/your/cert/files';
    shell_exec("openssl smime -sign -signer ".$sslPath."/certificate.crt -inkey ".$sslPath."/private-key.pem -certfile ".$sslPath."/ca-chain.pem -nodetach -outform der -in ".$inputFile." -out ".$outputFile);
}
?>
```

**4. Generate your profile and sign it**

Generate it as you need, and then call the method above to make a signed copy of it.

```
<?php
sslSignProfileToFile( "/path/to/your/unsigned-profile.mobileconfig", "/path/to/your/signed-profile.mobileconfig");
?>
```

**5. ENJOY!**

Then it's up to you :

- if you are in an AJAX request like me, you can return back in the body the URL to the signed profile to download
- if you were using a classic form POST action, you can just do a header redirect [like explained here](http://www.rootmanager.com/iphone-ota-configuration/iphone-ota-setup-with-signed-mobileconfig.html) (not tested by myself)

Answer (score 0):

If just for sign issue, I've answered one before, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917093/9297400

```php
/**
 * Sign MobileConfig
 *
 * @return string
 */
function signMobileConfig (
    string $file_full_pathname,
    string $certificate_pathname,
    string $private_key_pathname,
    bool $remove_file = true
) {
    openssl_pkcs7_sign(
        $file_full_pathname,
        $file_full_pathname.'.sig',
        file_get_contents($certificate_pathname),
        file_get_contents($private_key_pathname),
        [], 0
    );

    $signed = file_get_contents($file_full_pathname.'.sig');

    if ($remove_file) {
        unlink($file_full_pathname.'.sig');
        unlink($file_full_pathname);
    }

    $trimmed = preg_replace('/(.+\n)+\n/', '', $signed, 1);
    return base64_decode($trimmed);
}
```

[result of signed config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTSoM.png) ( <10 reputation, so click to see result)

Feel free to modify the code above to fulfill your demands.